# Can you Ready an attack using the Cleave feat(s)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, attack, readied-action

If I use the [Ready](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Ready) action stating 'I use a Cleave attack when an enemy comes within range' for...

> You can ready a standard action, a move action, a swift action, or a free action. To do so, specify the action you will take and the conditions under which you will take it.

...which, if any, of these Feats would/not be usable as a Ready Action:

- [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat/)
- [Great Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat-final/)
- [Cleaving Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleaving-finish-combat/)
- [Improved Cleaving Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-cleaving-finish-combat/)
- [Cleave Through](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/cleave-through-combat-dwarf/) (Dwarf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

*[(Great)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat-final/) [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat/)* specifies using a standard action, and as per the text you quoted that is valid for Readying an action.

> Benefit: **As a standard action**, you can make a single attack at your full base attack bonus against a foe within reach.

*[(Improved)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-cleaving-finish-combat/) [Cleaving Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleaving-finish-combat/)* is a passive effect that procs on any melee attack, so would be valid for a readied attack, supposing you meet the prerequisites of reducing an opponent to 0 up.

> Benefit: **If you make a melee attack**, and your target drops to 0 or fewer hit points as a result of your attack, you can make another melee attack using your highest base attack bonus against another opponent within reach.

<sup>Note: I don't think that *[Improved Cleaving Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-cleaving-finish-combat/)* would apply to a readied action attack, but only because I don't see how you'd be able to wreak so much carnage from just one standard!</sup>

*[Cleave Through](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/cleave-through-combat-dwarf/)* is, also, a passive effect that procs from a *[(Great)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat-final/) [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat/)* attack, so would also be valid if used from a readied action.

> Benefit: **When using *Cleave* or *Great Cleave***, if your initial attack hits, you may take a single 5-foot step as a free action before making your additional attacks.

<sup>*All emphasis my own.*</sup>

---

So long as the attacks you are making all stem from the one standard action, I see no reason why you can't cleave through a horde of enemies: It's not that much different from a *[Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/)*, after all!

Comment: Fireball isn't a dwarf whose avererage dpr is around 46 per target with no limit per day. =P fair point though. Asking for a 13th level one-shot.